# Angular child component view is not updating when changes are triggered from parent

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular and I'm struggling with some basic problem.
I have a module which tries to show an overlay (2nd module).
The overlay has a function show() which when called from the parent doesn't update the child html. If it's called from the child's onInit() - it works fine.

I suppose I'm missing something simple, but cannot find it.
Can you help me figure out what's going on?

Here is the code:
parent view:

```
export class SalesComponent {
    constructor(private groupsSelectorOverlayComponent: GroupsSelectorOverlayComponent) {
    }

    onBtnGroupsClick() {
        // this is the problematic call. It changes the child's properties, but the child view is not updated
        this.groupsSelectorOverlayComponent.show(-1);
    }
}
```

the child view:

```
@Component({
    ...
})
export class GroupsSelectorOverlayComponent implements OnInit {
    public isOpen: boolean = false;
    public groupsResponseData: GroupsResponseData = null;

    constructor(private stocksService: StocksService) {
        this.isOpen = false;
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
         // if we call show() from here, the view is updated
    }

    show(parentGroupId: number) {
        this.stocksService.getGroups(parentGroupId).subscribe((response) => {
            // we enter here, the values are updated, but when this is called from the parent, the view is not updated
            this.groupsResponseData = response;
            this.isOpen = true;
        });
    }
}
```

the child template:

```
    <ul *ngIf="groupsResponseData != null" class="groupPages">
        <li *ngFor="let page of groupsResponseData.groups_info" class="groupPage">
            <div class="title">{{ page.page_name }}</div>

            
        </li>
    </ul>
```

In app.module.ts I have this:

```
providers: [
    GroupsSelectorOverlayComponent
],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your parent, create a

```
@ViewChild(GroupsSelectorOverlayComponent)  
   child:GroupsSelectorOverlayComponent
```

Then call it like this:

```
this.child.show=(-1);
```

But remember you cannot call it until after all the views are initialized. Otherwise this.child will be undefined.

Don't forget

```
ChangeDetectorRef.DetectChanges();
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! And somehow it worked even without calling ChangeDetectorRef.DetectChanges()

Comment: Just remember that Angular has it's own layout flow, it always runs as soon as it sees a parent or child component.  This means that subsequent changes like filling in data from a getRequest require the detectChanges which is asking Angular to re-render the control.   Here's an article on why https://dev.to/jwp/angular-why-doesn-t-my-data-show-up-4efm

Comment: I'm happy it worked but I'd rather communicate parent-child components through Input Output and OnChanges lifecycle rather than modifying the natural component's lifecycle behave